# Concatenate table name postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, plpgsql

I want to use a function that assign the value of a query to a variable. However the name of the name of the table is derived from the output of previous lines in my function.

```
ref_A int 
ref_B int 
...
select count(*) into ref_C from "table" || ref_B || ref_A
```

In this case, the name of the table is "table refA refB"
The problem is that the syntax is wrong. Apparently, I need to use a dynamic query to concatenate the name of the name, but I don't see how I can assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Tip: RTFM
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 0):

As already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140861/concatenate-table-name-postgresql-function#comment135991166_77140861), you're looking for [`EXECUTE...INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN): [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pn3gTTvI)

```
create table "table21" as select n from generate_series(1,9,1) g(n);

create function my_func() returns int language plpgsql as $func$
declare
  ref_A int := 1;
  ref_B int := 2;
  ref_C int;
  your_table_name text:='table'|| ref_B || ref_A ;
begin
  execute format($dyn_sql$
                 select count(*) from %1$I 
                 $dyn_sql$,
                 your_table_name) 
          into ref_C;--this right here
  return ref_C;
end $func$;

select * from my_func();
```

| my_func |
| --- |
| 9 |